# Is possible to find a close form for $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(n-k)}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(n-k)}$
Thank you for your help

Comment: [Probably not](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2F(k+(n-k)),+%7Bk,+1,+n-1%7D%5D)

Comment: That would give a closed formula for the harmonic numbers, so it's quite unlikely.

Comment: I fixed a 'little' typo in my answer: The right answer is $\displaystyle\color{#00f}{2H_{n - 1} \over n}$ instead of $\require{cancel}\cancel{2H_{n} \over n}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\Big(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\Big)=\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} \sim \frac{2}{n}\log n.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over k\left(n - k\right)} =
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over k} +
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over n - k} =
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over k} +
{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over n - \left(n - k\right)} =
{2 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\displaystyle{2H_{n - 1} \over n}}
\end{align}